# Как автоматически создавать backup на виртуальном хостинге?

Tags: php, mysql, резервное-копирование

Есть достаточно рутинная задача по созданию копии файлов по FTP м MYSQL. И зачастую отказыватся переходить на виртуальные машины.
Однако автоматические бекапы необходимы. Или в облако разработчика или же  на FTP.

Есть ли варианты бекапирования с таких сайтов при помощи стороннего сервера имея в наличии FTP и MYSQL доступы?

Comment: По моему  многие хостинги предлагают эту услугу ( например у мастерхоста даже в самом дешевом тарифе есть "Резервное копирование" ) .. или вопрос в чем то другом?

Comment: Я о автоматическом резервном копировании. В ручную много где есть. Суть беды состоит в том, что клиент возлагает ответственность  за бекапирования, дав доступ к FTP и MYSQL. И таких клиентов много.

Comment: @Batanichek мелкие недосайтики располагаются на всяких дырохостах... А нормальные проекты распологаются на собственном серваке о своей  структурой и защитой..... Соответственно и вопрос - что делать со своим добром? Как делать бэкапы и прочее..... Вам про фому, а вы про ерёму...... хорошо что в гугл не послали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а где в вопросе понятно , что это собственный ну или хотя бы виртуальный сервер? ( на мой взгляд [виртуальном хостинге](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) предполагает что то не крупное)

Comment: @Batanichek Проблема не в том, что это дырявый хостинг. Может у него есть бекапы. Но ответственность на нас. И у нас есть только доступы FTP и MYSQL. Как это автиматизировать, чтобы как на нормальном сервере через 15 минут сайт в строю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы правы, проблем в предостовляемых клиентом доступах и ответственности.

Comment: На [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/239699/) есть статья на это счет ( вроде)

Comment: Читал, однако есть только доступ к FTP и MYSQL. Крона к сожалению нет. Ставить человека тоже не вариант.

Comment: на виндовс есть [вот](http://superuser.com/questions/52440/ftp-bat-file-windows-scheduled-task) пример настройки в планировщике задачки по скачиванию с ftp, думаю там же можно настроить и выкладывание куда то. ( или [вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666819/mysql-database-backup-automatically-on-a-windows-server) )

Comment: Для бэкапа mysql есть замечательная утилита mysqldump которая может сдампить как базу, так и нужную таблицу.

Comment: Это все не то. Я хочу имея FTP и MYSQL иметь функционал ISPManager или же Vesta. Тут откат не автоматизирован.